# SQL query with subqueries based on base values

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

Good morning; I have two tables that I am trying to work with to develop a single query with subquery and having issues if someone could help.

First Table - [MPA_Desc] - *There is more data I parsed for example*

```
MPAID Color Model Side
  1    085   x1    R
  2    777   x1    R
  3    085   x1    L
  4    777   x1    L
```

Second Table - [Paintsched] - *There is more data I parsed for example*

```
Lot  MPAID Amount
 1    1     100
 2    2     250
 3    4     100
 4    2     100
```

I am trying to get this as my query result:

```
Color   R      L
 085   100     0
 777   350    100
```

This is the query and subquery I am using, It's incomplete and doesn't have the "LH" calculations in it because I want to get the RH right first:

```
Select distinct(mp.Color), rh.RH
from MPA_Desc MP
right join (Select MPA_Desc.MPAID, MPA_Desc.Color, nullif(sum(qty),0) as RH from PaintSched inner join MPA_Desc on PaintSched.MPAID = MPA_Desc.MPAID 
where side = 'r' group by MPA_Desc.MPAID,MPA_Desc.Color) RH
ON mp.MPAID = rh.MPAID
 where Model = 'x1'
```

But this however gives me the following result:

```
Color    R     
085     100
085     NULL
777     350
777     Null
```

I know it's from my full join but I need to show the Null's as "0" and I thought nullif would work but apparently not in a subquery. Secondly I need it to just show the List of color codes by model in the original query and seperate out the sums based on RH or LH parts. Any help would be great, thank you all!

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function... It's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` and works on the whole selected rows. To make things clearer, remove those redundant parentheses, i.e. `Select distinct mp.Color, rh.RH ...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `PIVOT`

```
DECLARE @MPA_Desc TABLE (MPAID INT, Color VARCHAR(5),  Model VARCHAR(5), Side VARCHAR(5))
INSERT INTO @MPA_Desc VALUES
(1 , '085', 'x1', 'R'),
(2 , '777', 'x1', 'R'),
(3 , '085', 'x1', 'L'),
(4 , '777', 'x1', 'L')

DECLARE @Paintsched TABLE (Lot INT, MPAID INT,  Amount INT)
INSERT INTO @Paintsched VALUES
(1 ,1 , 100),
(2 ,2 , 250),
(3 ,4 , 100),
(4 ,2 , 100)

SELECT Color, ISNULL(R,0) R, ISNULL( L,0) L FROM 
    ( SELECT Color, Side, Amount FROM @MPA_Desc D
        INNER JOIN @Paintsched P ON D.MPAID = P.MPAID ) SRC
        PIVOT (SUM(Amount) FOR Side IN ([R],[L])) PVT
```

Result:

```
Color R           L
----- ----------- -----------
085   100         0
777   350         100
```

Comment: This looks promising but I have about 1000 different colors and combinations, I want them listed dynamically so that when a new one gets added I don't have to go in and declare it, Is there a way to support that?

Comment: You don't need to declare any colour. Declarations all for test purpose. You can use the query with your actual tables.

Answer (score 1):

You need conditional aggregation :

```
select md.Color, 
       sum(case when Side = 'R' then ps.amount else 0 end),
       sum(case when Side = 'L' then ps.amount else 0 end)
from MPA_Desc md inner join
     Paintsched ps
     on ps.MPAID = md.MPAID
group by md.Color;
```

Comment: Thanks mate! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following (Its Dynamic) -:

```
Declare @sql varchar(MAX),@query nvarchar(MAX)
select @sql=stuff((select  distinct ', sum(case when side='''+side+''' then amount else 0 end) as '+side from [MPA_Desc] FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '' )
set @query='select color,'+@sql+' from [MPA_Desc] m join [Paintsched] n on m.MPAID=n.MPAID group by color'
EXEC sp_sqlexec @query
```

SQL Server 2014

Comment: Hey man I really appreciate the help, quick question, I have more colors that are in my MPA_desc table that I need to show R and L values for even if they're zero. Any idea on how to make that happen?

Comment: Yeah this query ll give you the desired result. Its a dynamic query as I mentioned on top of the query and faster thn pivoting as well.